# Why did Allah create at all? A simplification, why we are created?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, creation

I have a fundamental question.

I can understand concept of heaven and hell. I can understand that we are all in an exam in this world. I can understand so many concepts after I believe in Allah. However, what is the purpose of creation? What did Allah create at all?

Comment: 51:56 explains the reason we were created, Now can you please clarify, is the verse not answering your question? if not then why ?

Comment: My interpretation of the verse is like a warning that the jinn and the mankind should not to worship anything but Allah. I struggle to understand the purpose of creation from this verse.

Answer (score 0):

We are created so we can worship Allah.

**“And I (Allaah) created not the jinn and mankind except that they should worship Me (Alone)”**

[al-Dhaariyaat 51:56]

Comment: I did not understand that verse properly. Is worshipping Allah our only purpose in this world?

Comment: I guess the next question would be why does Allah need to be worshipped, to the extent that he will burn the ones who don't eternally?